# How can I get Keychain Access back?

Tags: macos, keychain-access

I bought a used MacBook Air running macOS 10.15.x Catalina. Being a newbie to Macs, I somehow corrupted Keychain Access. I am unable to delete what is left of it. The folder in `/Library` is also missing. I have tried resetting but it does not work. What should I do to regain a new Keychain Access?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall Catalina in-place. If you re-install the same version of macOS on top of an existing installation, it does a repair-install to bring back any missing/corrupted pieces of the system.

As always, you should first make a backup *and test your backup*, just in case. But you do not need to do an erase+install, you can just install on top of the existing installation.